# jquery ui dialog box not showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to show a jquery dialog box with code like:

```
var message = "Request processed successfully";
$('<div>'+message+'</div>').dialog({
   buttons:{
     'Add More':function(){window.location='index.py?mode=Receivable&cm=Add';},
     'View All':function(){window.location='index.py?mode=Receivable&cm=Browse&freshLoad=1';}
   }   
});
```

The text, and buttons (including 'close') all appear and look/work properly, but there is no containing box around them. I'm not getting any errors (ie: it can find all the images/scripts/etc. that it's looking for). I can give more details, but has anyone ran into a similar problem?

Comment: Do you have your jQuery UI CSS included and referenced in the page? I have this happen to me if I forget the CSS.

Comment: Correct. Thank you. If you submit this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lack of formatting in jQuery UI is usually due to bad or missing CSS. Make sure you have the jQuery UI CSS code and images included and the CSS file linked in your page. It should then work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Using your code I was able to get it to work correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/bzGEE/

Check your JS and CSS paths to ensure they aren't 404ing.